# How i can install selenium in android studio?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

When I try to set up a chromedriver with WebdriverManager in my Java Android studio project, I get the error:
(Exception reading resolution cache as a properties file)

My build.gradle dependancies are:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.4.0'
    implementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.3.0'
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getData();
    }

    public void getData() {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        service.execute(() -> {

             
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

                driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

                Log.d(TAG, "title: " + driver.getTitle());

                driver.quit();

        });
    }
```

The Error:

```
2022-08-30 10:47:26.081 27879-27998/com.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
    Process: com.test, PID: 27879
    io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: Exception reading resolution cache as a properties file
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.cache.ResolutionCache.<init>(ResolutionCache.java:86)
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.getResolutionCache(WebDriverManager.java:1648)
    .....
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        ....
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

I need help! Thanks.

Comment: Update the question with the error stacktrace.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.